# pandas: sum of each column results a NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row

I have a dataframe in pandas as below. I am trying to add a row with row-name ="Total", which is the sum of each column. I am using the following code : **df.loc["Total"] = df.sum(axis =1)**

I am getting NaN as a sum of each column. Any idea why and how to solve it ?

[dataframe with "Total" row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QXbb.jpg)

Comment: Use `df.loc["Total"] = df.astype(float).sum()` or `df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()`

Comment: Please use text formatting rather than pictures to show your examples.

Comment: Thanks, df.astype() function worked @jezrael

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
```

Or if need convert first string values of columns to float:

```
df.loc["Total"] = df.astype(float).sum()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
print (df)
       A   B   C  D   E   F
0      1   4   7  1   5   7
1      2   5   8  3   3   4
2      3   6   9  5   6   3
Total  6  15  24  9  14  14
```